# How to see the content of tensorflow tensor keras Input layer?

Tags: python, keras

I want to see the content of the below tensorflow tensor given by Input class of keras

```py
from keras.layers import Input
sequence_input = Input(shape=(128,), dtype='int32')
# How to see the content of sequence input
sequence_input
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
with tf.Session() as sess:  
  print(sequence_input.eval())
```

```
Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseSession.__del__ of <tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x7fa11ecac8d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 763, in __del__
    if self._session is not None:
AttributeError: 'Session' object has no attribute '_session'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-eaa497285237> in <module>()
      5 import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
      6 import numpy as np
----> 7 with tf.Session(session=sess) as sess:
      8   print(sequence_input.eval())

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session'
```

I have tried several solutions offered on how to see the content of the tensorflow tensor but I get errors and could not find a working code.I have included on solution proposed above with the error. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

you want to see the content of the tensor given a specific input? or just the general configuration of this tensor? anyway you can use keras Model class to define your model,  for example:

```
input = Input(shape=(128,), dtype='int32')
output = input
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, output)
```

than you can access the model layers - model.layers[0] for example will be the input layer. However I'm not sure I understand you're purpose since the input tensor will have no value unless you provide some data to the model...